# Blender Ivy export as DAE

Tags: export, collada

How do I export BlenderIvy as a Collada (DAE) file? (Blender to SketchUp)
3ds worked, but not with leaves instanced & with materials...
DAE now comes in as a blank file...

Comment: IvyGen addon makes a curve, which might be the issue. Convert to a mesh first.

Comment: The scale with sketchup and blender is really different, it could've imported as a speck. try scaling all selection.

Comment: I can't remember if Sketchup has an outliner, but check there if it has one to double check that it actually doesn't exist, instead of actually being very small or at an odd location as Vince Scalia mentioned.

Comment: Changing to curve to mesh did the trick. Scale is fine with dea. UV mapping and textures are not comming thru to ShetchUp, but geometry looks fine. Leaves are not instanced...

Comment: So is it solved, or what exactly is the issue now?

Comment: The original question was solved by converting the curve to a mesh. There are two new issues: 1.Blender exported instanes are not imported as instances to SketchUp. 2. SketchUp looses textures and UV in the imported file.